# How to open child activity directly in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I have this use case where I open Settings activity (call it parent activity) and another child settings activity (call it child activity). The normal flow is: `Open parent activity -> click some button -> open child activity`. So far so good.

Now, in the specific use case, where a floating button (like `chat-head` - which is always present on the screen) should directly open the child activity. The caveat is that if the Settings activity is already present, the child activity should behave as if the child was opened with the same flow as the `Settings->child`.

What should be the correct approach for this? One is that I check if the settings activity is already running, I add a flag to the intent and open the Settings screen only which on checking the flag, will open the child activity. But checking if Settings is already running might not be recommended or maybe there's some better approach.

Comment: I think you have to use fragment as a child view.

Comment: You should follow single activity with multiple fragment architecture see below link
https://github.com/abbas-oveissi/SingleAcitvityPattern

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things need to be done:

1. in your manifest, child activity should point to parent using `android:parentActivityName` attribute value
2. when you're exiting your child activity (via "up" or system back handlers for example), invoke something like this:

   Intent upIntent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
   TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
       .addNextIntentWithParentStack(upIntent)
       .startActivities();